# Error accessing my webapp running inside my Azure vm using public IP

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, azure, azure-virtual-network

I know this is not the ideal way but nonetheless, I created an Azure VM and deployed my application running react.js as frontend, springboot as backend and database as mysql. I used already created docker images from dockerhub to run the containers. After running all the images as containers, if I user RDP to get a GUI for my VM, I can login and connect and all the components work fine.

But when I use public ip to open the homepage of my app, it is throwing me an error saying that it cannot connect to **http://localhost:8081** which is my springboot url. Note that I am able to access my react-app running in my vm but not the springboot backend.

Here are the snippets-

**WebPage**
React-app running on Azure vm accessed using public ip

[image: React-app running on Azure vm accessed using public ip]

**Error**
Error when react tries to access springboot for api calls

[image: Error when react tries to access springboot for api calls]

Just to clarify here are all the port numbers I am using

80- React app and also given as inbound port number in my virtual machine
8081- Springboot running in my vm

Answer (score 0):

As react.js frontend will be running in the browser of users' side, the `localhost` here is users side localhost, not your Azure VM's, so that users can't access your VM port.

In your react.js frontend code, you should specify your spring-boot URL as `http://<your VM piblic IP>:8081` instead of localhost. And you need also to open the 8081 port in the Azure VM network security group so that this port could be accessed by the public network. Detailes see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).

Comment: How do i do this because I want my app to run on my localmachine for which I have to give the address of spring as localhost:8081 and for my vm I need to give it <vm public ip>:8081 ?

Comment: @PoojanKhatri, yes if you want your server to be accessed by public network, you should specify your VM public IP in your  react.js frontend